# c# List of KeyValuePair to Multicolumn CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox, keyvaluepair

In my project I am making a list with key-value pairs of `string` and `elementId`. The reason for making a list is because I want to add all the items to a `checkedListBox` later on in the code.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, ElementId>> kvPairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ElementId>>();
```

When I have my collection of elements, I am adding the element name and the element id to the key-value pair:

```
foreach (Element viewElement in viewCollector)
{
    kvPairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, ElementId>(viewElement.Name, viewElement.Id));
}
```

What I want to do next, is add these key-value pairs to a `checkedListBox` where the name is added in a separate column of the `elementId`.

But I cant seem to find where/how to add a second column. There seems to be no overload method in `checkedListBox.Items.Add()` to write to multiple columns.

Edit:

Using WinForms.

Also the whole `checkedListBox.MultiColumn` doesn't seem to make sense if there is no way to define columns. I'm really confused here.

Comment: Winforms, WPF, ... ?

Comment: @Jim Sorry, using Winforms

Comment: this can't be done with a `CheckedListBox`,  consider using *DataGridView* or *ListView*.

Answer (score 1):

well as far as I know, you cannot add a second column, but you could override the SelectedListBox ItemTemplate in a way like this:

Well you have do adjust your binding as needed - but this should work out. 
Probably you want to change the StackPanel though for something working out for you better,

```
 <ListBox >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding IsChecked}">
                    <StackPanel >
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=...}" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=...}"></Label>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=...}"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: How come you assume that the OP is using WPF ?

Comment: Mh, well you are completly right - I just checked and well there is a CheckedListBox in WinForms aswell, I didn't know that. 
@Dante1986 can you let us know if you need this for winforms? I could change my answer then

Comment: @TripleEEE sorry for beeing unclear. Im using winforms. Strange enough the checkedlistbox does have `checkedListBox.MultiColumn = true` but no idea if it does anything and how it should work

Comment: Hey Dante, no problem at all. I'm busy right now, but if you're not in a hurry I'll provide you the answer tomorrow, if anybody is faster ;)